# docker-compose giving the error proxyconnect tcp: EOF

Tags: docker, proxy, wireshark

I am running Docker on Windows behind a corporate firewall and proxy server, running a Linux image. I am getting the error `"proxyconnect tcp: EOF"` when I run docker-compose up.
I run a wireshark trace and I am getting many `Error: STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND` errors, for docker-credential-desktop, docker-credential-wincred.exe, mime.types.

Has anyone else encountered these problems running Docker on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was inside Docker Desktop. I set the https proxy when our proxy service doesn't use https. I used http for the httpsProxy and it worked. But one thing I don't understand: The settings were correct in docker-compose.yml but incorrect in Docker Desktop. It seems docker desktop overrides docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the docker daemon is not able to connect to the internet directly to pull the images.

Go to Preferences/Settings and configure proxy settings.

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

Use the respective proxy values to connect to the internet from your network